# How to update dictionaries inside two separate lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two list :

```
list1 = [{"name":"xyz" ,"roll":"r" , "sap_id":"z"} , {"name":"pqr" ,"roll":"s" , "sap_id":"w"}]
list2 = [{"cn_number":"26455"} , {"cn_number":"26456"}]
```

I want a new list like:

```
new_list = [{"name":xyz ,"roll":"r" , "sap_id":"z","cn_number":"26455"} , {"name":"pqr" ,"roll":"s" , "sap_id":"w","cn_number":"26456"}]
```

**I tried the following method:**

```
new_list = [i.update(j) for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
```

but got some nasty error

Comment: "but got some nasty error" doesn't help at all. For an analogy, if you go to your doctor, would you say "I got some nasty pain"?

Comment: I don't get an error. Maybe you meant a _bug_, whereby the new list is `[None, None]`, because `i.update(j)` updates `i` but doesn't return it. If you use `for i, j in zip(list1, list2): i.update(j)`, `list1` will now be the desired new list, but such mutation isn't good practice.

Comment: I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 11):

This syntax works for [python3.5+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) to merge two dictionaries `z = {**x, **y}`

```
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 13:15:42)
>>> list1 = [{"name":"xyz" ,"roll":"r" , "sap_id":"z"} , {"name":"pqr" ,"roll":"s" , "sap_id":"w"}]
>>> list2 = [{"cn_number":"26455"} , {"cn_number":"26456"}]
>>> new_list = [{**i, **j} for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
>>> new_list
[{'name': 'xyz', 'roll': 'r', 'sap_id': 'z', 'cn_number': '26455'}, {'name': 'pqr', 'roll': 's', 'sap_id': 'w', 'cn_number': '26456'}]
```

More information: [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (take union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/1392943)

Comment: It works on Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 13:15:42)

Comment: @AKX, nope, `|` and `|=` were added in 3.9, read the link you provided. `{**x, **y}` is pre 3.9.

Comment: Oop, my bad there. (Fixed the docs link in my answer.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Python 3.5+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448) dict merging syntax:

```
new_list = [{**a, **b} for (a, b) in zip(list1, list2)]
```

results in

```
[
  {'name': 'xyz', 'roll': 'r', 'sap_id': 'z', 'cn_number': '26455'}, 
  {'name': 'pqr', 'roll': 's', 'sap_id': 'w', 'cn_number': '26456'},
]
```

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way to do this is with `collections.ChainMap` which is made specifically for combining multiple dictionaries. Read more on the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap).

```
from collections import ChainMap

[dict(ChainMap(i,j)) for i,j in zip(list1, list2)]
```

```
[{'cn_number': '26455', 'name': 'xyz', 'roll': 'r', 'sap_id': 'z'},
 {'cn_number': '26456', 'name': 'pqr', 'roll': 's', 'sap_id': 'w'}]
```

> NOTE: Depending on how you want to use each element of the updated list, you could use a generator and avoid using `dict()` over `ChainMap` object to still get what you need without using unnecessary memory! `ChainMap` gives you a single updatable view of the multiple dictionaries by still referencing the original objects.

```
#efficient way -

#EDITED: lesser keystrokes as suggested by @Kelly
g = map(ChainMap, list1, list2) 

#g = (ChainMap(i,j) for i,j in zip(list1, list2))

next(g).get('sap_id')
```

```
z
```

Comment: We can also use `[dict(ChainMap(*t)) for t in zip(list1, list2)]`.

Comment: `g = map(ChainMap, list1, list2)`. No point writing your own generator expression for that.

Comment: Thanks for the input @KellyBundy. Either works! but the map does use lesser keystrokes (code golfers!) so I have updated my answer :)